# Modifying reddit's ranking algorithm to change content more often?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ranking

I use reddit's ranking algorithm on my site in order to rank what's "hot" and what's not. Here is a simple explanation of how reddit's ranking algorithm works:

https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-reddit-ranking-algorithms-work-ef111e33d0d9#.igk62pe0x

Specifically, this part:

```
# Rewritten code from /r2/r2/lib/db/_sorts.pyx

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from math import log

epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)

def epoch_seconds(date):
    td = date - epoch
    return td.days * 86400 + td.seconds + (float(td.microseconds) / 1000000)

def score(ups, downs):
    return ups - downs

def hot(ups, downs, date):
    s = score(ups, downs)
    order = log(max(abs(s), 1), 10)
    sign = 1 if s > 0 else -1 if s < 0 else 0
    seconds = epoch_seconds(date) - 1134028003
    return round(sign * order + seconds / 45000, 7)
```

However, I found that, although this algorithm works very well, it doesn't change up content as often as I would like it to.

How can I modify the algorithm to do this? What numbers or parts of the algorithm would I need to modify in order for content on my site to change more frequently?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dividing `seconds` by 45000, you can divide it by a smaller number so that recent posts will have more significant impact and the feed will change more frequently. You can also tweak with the base of the logarithmic function or use a function with a different growth rate like square root function.

Comment: What exactly is the 45000 referring to? Why does the algorithm divide by 45000?

Comment: If you post an article at time T1, a number T will be the difference between time T1 and 08/12/2005, 07:46:43 AM in seconds. While calculating the hotness, we add T/45000 so that recent posts have more hotness. If you want the impact of recency to grow, you should decrease the constant from 45000.

Comment: @user6357859 45000 is 12.5 hours in seconds, the decay time of a hot story on Reddit